# How can I get images and text from an Instagram post?

Tags: java, telegram-bot

I am writing a Telegram bot in Java. The user must send the bot a link to the post from [Instagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instagram), and the bot in return should send the user pictures and text from the post to the user. How can I do this?

I tried to use the Instagram API, but there aren't any necessary methods.

Comment: Which API docs did you consult so far?

Comment: The Instagram4j API doesn't have much documentation, so it's hard to figure out how to get the data of a particular post.
API link: https://github.com/instagram4j/instagram4j

Comment: This uses Instagram's private api, so I would not expect to get any support. Try to use one of the officially supported at https://developers.facebook.com/products/instagram/apis/

Comment: Well, many people advised me to use the parser, but after a day I did not find a normal solution